# Improving RDP performance

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

How can I improve RDP performance? I'm on an 8mb line, and I have disabled all the fancy features like visual styles. One page said if I set a low speed, that too will increase performance. Is there any proof in this?

Also, there was an ad here about an application/technology which can increase RDP performance by x20. Has anyone used this?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt everyone has seen the ad and/or noticed it.  Instead of just saying their was one can you provide a link to the specific product/service?

Comment: What exactly is slow? Why would you enhance 'the performance'?.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to watch movies or playing games over RDP? At my point of view disable sound, don't use multimedia fancy gadgets - it is not designed for that. Try Citrix to save bandwith or ThinPrint if you want to print large documents or heavy pictures.

-> Never work with your mapped local drives, also use of local CD or DVD is a 'do not', except to copy something from or to them.

Comment: +1 Citrix ICA performs much better over slow and/or high-latency links

Answer (score 1):

Setting the connection to a lower speed (e.g. 56k, etc.) simply controls which RDP features are enabled or disabled - the lower the speed, the more features are disabled.

Citrix is supposed to do a better job of managing bandwidth and applications not really appropriate for terminal services (e.g. animations) but will still not be as good as local applications.

I have seen one situation some time ago with older Wyse WinTerms that have absolutely abysmal performance when the user is typing in a large rich text edit field (e.g. CKEdit, but I don't know if that's the actual one being used) in a browser on the remote session. We never found a resolution for that, but took the simpler route of swapping the WinTerms for a different model running a different OS. It's been a while, but I believe they were in the 5150 family and we switched between Windows CE and the Wyse thin client OS - I don't recall which version had the problem.

You say you're on an 8MB line, but that's presumably your download speed. What's the upload speed of the site hosting the terminal server? If you're on a VPN, what kind of bandwidth/performance do you get through the tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting your connection to a slower speed can improve performance, because more features are disabled.

You can turn-down color depth, disable local resource access, and a variety of other things to improve the connection speed.

But improving performance will really depend on what you're doing: if you're trying to run Visual Studio over an RDP connection, it's gonna be slow.

If you're using Word, it'll be pretty quick.